# Highlight minimum values every row using seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to highlight minimum values of each row using the same color:

[image: I am trying to highlight minimum values of each row using the same color.]

For instance, the first row minimum is 0.3. I want to highlight it with blue color. Similarly, for the second row, 0.042 and so on.

Here's the code.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

Pe = np.random.rand(5,5)

annot=True
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1)    
ax1 = sns.heatmap(Pe, linewidth=0.5,ax=ax1,annot=annot)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop through the rows, find the index of the minimum, and draw a rectangle there.  Setting `clip_on=False` prevents that the rectangles would be clipped by the border.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

Pe = np.random.rand(5, 5)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 4))
sns.set_style('white')

sns.heatmap(Pe, linewidth=0.5, annot=True, ax=ax1)
for ind, row in enumerate(Pe):
    min_col = np.argmin(row)
    ax1.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((min_col, ind), 1, 1, fc='none', ec='skyblue', lw=5, clip_on=False))

sns.heatmap(Pe, mask=Pe != Pe.min(axis=1, keepdims=True), annot=True, lw=2, linecolor='black', clip_on=False,
            cmap=ListedColormap(['skyblue']), cbar=False, ax=ax2)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap with highlights]

PS: To create animations, the [Celluloid library](https://github.com/jwkvam/celluloid) is a lightweight option:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from celluloid import Camera

Pe = np.random.rand(5, 5)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
camera = Camera(fig)
sns.set_style('white')

row_array = np.arange(Pe.shape[0]).reshape(-1, 1)
for row in range(Pe.shape[0]):
    sns.heatmap(Pe, mask=(Pe != Pe.min(axis=1, keepdims=True)) | (row < row_array),
                annot=True, lw=2, linecolor='black', clip_on=False,
                cmap=ListedColormap(['skyblue']), cbar=False, ax=ax1)
    camera.snap()

animation = camera.animate(interval=800)
animation.save('animation.gif')
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap animation]

For more complicated animations, matplotlib's [animation API](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html) can be considered.

Comment: Thanks so much. Is it possible to use one color for all the minimum values and show in a separate heatmap?

Comment: You can use a mask to hide all cells apart from the minima.

Comment: Thanks. How do I create an animation? For instance, the first minimum (from first row) appears and a little later the second minimum and so on.