# Labeling elements on heatmap using Python

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

[image] I want to label the elements in the following fashion at various iterations and ultimately create an animation. Here is the code. I want to directly add patch using the matrix 'b' instead of adding it manually.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

a = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6],
              [7,8,9]])

b = np.array([[1, 2],
 [4, 1],
 [7, 4]])

annot=True
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)  
ax1 = sns.heatmap(a, linewidth=0.5,ax=ax1,annot=annot)
ax1.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((0,0), 2,1,fc='none', ec='skyblue', lw=5, clip_on=False))
ax1.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((0,0), 1,2,fc='none', ec='skyblue', lw=5, clip_on=False))
ax1.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((0,1), 1,2,fc='none', ec='skyblue', lw=5, clip_on=False))
```

Comment: See e.g. [Highlight minimum values every row using seaborn heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70927880/highlight-minimum-values-every-row-using-seaborn-heatmap/70928130#70928130) about drawing rectangles over heatmap cells and creating a simple animation.

Comment: Please, please, don't ask [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70951151/animation-using-seaborn-in-python) again and again.  Instead, edit the question and show what you tried and where you got stuck.  Also note that it might take more than 24 hours before sufficient people have had time to study your question.

Comment: Also, please don't import `pylab` which is deprecated for more than 10 years and only exists for very old code to run. Use `matplotlib.pyplot` instead.